# How to create a sort of abstract super test class in JUnit 4?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Consider the following concrete scenario: Someone has created a lot of tests that fully test the functionality to which a class implementing `Collection<E>` must adhere. How is it then possibly to use that test class (in some way) to test concrete implementations of `Collection<E>`?

By example:

```
public class CollectionTest {
    //lots of tests here
}

public class ACollection<E> implements Collection<E> {
    //implementation and custom methods
}

public class BCollection<E> implements Collection<E> {
    //implementation and other custom methods
}
```

How should I then write the test classes such that least code duplication occurs?

```
public class ACollectionTest {
    //tests for Collection<E>, preferably not duplicated
    //tests for custom methods
}

public class BCollectionTest {
    //tests for Collection<E>, preferably not duplicated
    //tests for other custom methods
}
```

In other words, is it possible to "extend CollectionTest", but have its tests run on an instance of `ACollectionTest` or `BCollectionTest` (or more)? Note that the methods are still accessible once you use `ACollection<E>` as `Collection<E>` for example.

Comment: In guava, exists a base abstract test for the InmutableSet (for example)  with a bunch of methods to obtaint the colleciton, see [the abstract](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/collect/AbstractImmutableSetTest.java) and the implementations [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetTest.java) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSetTest.java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the base class:

```
protected Collection<Foo> collectionUnderTest;

@Test
public void shouldDoThis() {
    // uses collectionUnderTest
}

@Test
public void shouldDoThat() {
    // uses collectionUnderTest
}
```

In the subclass, specific to the ACollection implementation:

```
@Before
public void prepare() {
    this.collectionUnderTest = new ACollection<>();
}
```

Comment: I just saw this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724401/how-to-write-junit-tests-for-interfaces, does that here also mean that custom rules, etc. cannot be used anymore?

Comment: I don't see why they couldn't be used. But this is too vague. My advice would be: stop trying to guess or predict what will happen, what you can and can't do. Try doing it, and you'll see what happens.

Comment: Is it possible to apply `mocking` in such example?

Comment: @LeonidDashko Mocking is not useful here since the point is to actually call the real methods on the implementation