# Java Construct Generic Instance From Class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am trying to construct an instance of a generic class, with a type parameter. For example if have `ArrayList.class` and I want to initialize it with class `String.class`, how do I do that? I understand I can use `ArrayList.class.newInstance()` to create a new instance, but I can't pass in a type parameter. I want to do `new ArrayList<String>`, but instead of for that specific example, any class that has a type parameter.

Specifically, I am trying to [implement testing of different implementations of an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724401/how-to-write-junit-tests-for-interfaces#comment28660208_6724555), through subclassing of a JUnit test.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating a generic class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java)

Comment: Basically, you can't because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I don't think it is. That is asking how to initialize the type within a generic class. I am asking how to initialize a generic class with a type.

Comment: Since type information is erased at runtime and only useful for the static typecheck during compilation, why do you want to do this? In particular, there is *no difference* at runtime between an instance of `ArrayList<String>` and an instance of `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: Because then I know when I get, say, an item from my newly created ArrayList then I can use all the String methods on it

Comment: How would you know that? Can you give a code example?

Comment: Basically doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724401/how-to-write-junit-tests-for-interfaces#comment28660208_6724555 ill update to show my example

Comment: @Thilo you are right, I really don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that can just return an initialization of the generic class, without the type paremeter and just cast it to that paremeter.

For example:

```
private Class<? extends List> implementation = ArrayList.class;

private <E> List<E> newList(Class<E> itemClass) {
    try {
        return (List)implementation.newInstance();
    } catch (Throwable x) {
       return null;
    }
}

@Test
public void test1() {
    List<String> testInstance = newList(String.class);
    testInstance.add('hey');
    assertEquals(3, testInstance.get(0).lenght());
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't catch Throwable. Otherwise, yes you can do this this way. I would personally cast to `(List<E>)` and use a temp variable to annotate the assignment with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: you'll get a warning for this, though, about unchecked conversion.

Comment: @Thilo It's safe though as long as you don't put something in the List while it's raw.

Comment: that's right. But I am assuming that List is only an example. This may or may not be safe with the real interface (and implementations) that are being tested here.

Comment: Of course, triggering run time errors (like ClassCastException) is exactly what JUnit is for. So that should not be a problem.