# Testing action class which depends on the interface

Tags: java, testing, testng

TestNG 6.8.8

I have the following interface and implementation:

```
public interface HolderService {
    String str();
    //other-methods
}

public interface Act1{
    public String action(Collection<HolderService> context);
}

//The action class for testing    
public class ActImpl implements Act1{
    public String action(Collection<HolderService> context){
        //implementation
    }
}
```

The problem is the implementation of the `HolderService` is kind of messy to initialize it with test data which makes the test be quite large.

So my first thought was to write a simple test implementation and supply it with test data like this:

```
public class ActImplTest{

    @Test
    public void some_Test(){
        //...
    }

    private static class ServiceHolderTestImpl implemets HolderService{
        //Just a JavaBean with getters and setters
    }
}
```

But it looks a little wierd that in order for to make tests look simpler I need to provide some test implementation. Maybe there is another way to deal with the problem. I also looked at Parametrization, shown in this [***example***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724555/3663882), but it doesn't seem fit my needs.

Comment: That sounds like you want to use a mock of HolderService, right? In that case have a look at mocking frameworks like Mockito etc.

Comment: @Thomas Well, yes. But not in the way like [this](http://websystique.com/java/testing/testng-mockito-example-stubbing-void-methods/). I need a collection of initialized mock-instances, so mock-injection doesn't fit here.