# Testing interface implementations with testng

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

TestNG 6.8.8

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Act1{
    /**
    * Some contract
    */
    public String doAct(String input);
}
```

and a couple of its implementations

```
public class Act1Impl1 implements Act1{
   //...
}

public class Act1Impl2 implements Act1{
   //...
}
```

The issue is there are some general contracts which implementations must follow and I'd like to write a test for this common functionality in a separate test class, like this:

```
public class CommonAct1Test{

    @Test
    public void test_Case1(){ 
        Act1 act1; 
        //test act1 case 1
    }

    @Test
    public void test_Case2(){
        Act1 act1; 
        //test act1 case 2
    }

}
```

The problem here is that it's possible to add other implementations of `Act1` in the future. So, I need a way to easily add these implementations to the test.

***Why do I think `@DataProvider` doesn't fit***?
Because (as far as I understood) its main purpose is to support DDT, therefore provide different data sets for testing a single unit. But in my case I test different units on the same data set.

How could I do this correctly with TestNG. In `JUnit` we have `@RunWith` and a parameterized test as shown in [***this asnwer***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724555/3663882)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through dataprovider as such, as such your data IS different implementations of the interface.  Just so happens instead of actual data, code is your data :).

You can look at testng [Factory](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories) - achieves the same thing but probably you will get the feeling you are looking for - "test different units on the same data set"